# Calendar countdown timer widget

Tags: windows, calendar, timer, widget

can someone recommend widget for windows OS like countdown timer of day, month and year. I saw it in project misskey hub, but i don't found widgets like that for windows.

[image: Calendar countdown timer]

----------------------------------------